# Curved background image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve something like in the picture below (curved background image) from [state street](http://www.statestreet.com) website, but in CSS.

Thanks to posts from other users on stackoverflow, I've been able to create something a bit similar using border-radius, see http://jsfiddle.net/dg44thbr/9/

The issue is that my curve... is too curvy. I'd like it to be more "straight" like the state street one.

Is it possible in CSS?

Thanks,

[image]

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

div#back {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://wearepeak.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/testimonial.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 70% 60px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30% 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can try this one on for size: http://jsfiddle.net/dg44thbr/10/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

div#back {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://wearepeak.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/testimonial.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 250% 160px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  margin-left: -2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="back"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Almost what I'm looking for1 :) Is there a way to have the end of the curve (on the left) more straight?