# CSS div oval shape

Tags: html, css

[image: oval shape example image]

Can someone help me out making such a cut out from div?

Found possible solution,but dont have knowledge in SVG.Maybe someone can help me out.

HTML:

```
 <svg viewBox="0 0 400 150">
 <path opacity="0.6" fill="red" d="M0,10 Q0,0 10,0 Q195,40 390,0 Q400,0 400,10 Q390,75 400,140 Q400,150 390,150 Q195,100 10,150 Q0,150 0,140 Q10,75       0,10" />
 </svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curved background image in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952360/curved-background-image-in-css)

Comment: I don't think so. That one was about making a curve up top. This one is about making an oval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden
}

svg {
    left: 47%;
    position: relative;
    top: -24%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 2000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:-

```css
#oval_parent{
    background:black;
    width:200px;
    height:120px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#oval{
  
    width: 220px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:10px 0 0 -10px;  
    background: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="oval_parent">
    <div id="oval"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="oval"></div>
```

css:

```
.oval { width: 100px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%; background: red; overflow: hidden;}
```

The trick is to have one side bigger than the other. Overflow hidden to cut out the background stuff if you use an image.

Change the width and height depending on the direction of the oval.

Here's a JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/10cq0vmv/

Comment: Your initial posted question wasn't specific enough and that was the answer to that, now that you've posted the result you want to accomplish - yeah, you need something different

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is create a div right after the navigation and make curved png with Photoshop and apply it as background to that div. So in that way you have rectangle navigation and div with curved background after navigation.

```
.nav-bot{
    background: url(https://s23.postimg.org/jakqjag8r/nav_bot.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Here is example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkeca3d2/). 
**EDIT**
If you don't want to use image there is another way to do this Using css `gradient` and `box-shadow`.

```
.nav-bot{
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
    width: 104%;
    margin-left: -2%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -19px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wkeca3d2/2/) for that.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Have thought about that but they dont accept it as a valid solution